# Fishpig 3 column layout not working in page/post

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

Followed these instruction to display a 3 column layout for page/post:
[fishpig layout XML.](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/layout-xml/)

Used the local.xml of the theme in `app/design/frontend/my_theme/default/layout/local.xml`
but view is still default 2 column layout.

Comment: Can you post your local.xml file?

Comment: This is the original one, without fishpig code: [link](http://we.tl/0Hb3llfyhG)

Comment: Can you post the custom XML code you're using please?

Answer (score 0):

I have looked into this and tested a few things on your site (you provided access details via email) and found that the code at [this link](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/layout-xml/) does in fact work. The extension uses the layout handle 'wordpress_{{post_type}}_view' for each different post type. Therefore, for posts, you can change the root template with the following XML:

```
<wordpress_post_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</wordpress_post_view>
```

I have tested this on your site, added it to your theme's local.xml file and refreshed the layout cache. This has correctly changed the root template of your blog posts to the 3 column layout.

For pages, I used the following XML code:

```
<wordpress_page_view>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</wordpress_page_view>
```

Again, I added this to your local.xml file, refreshed the cache and then your Pages had a 3 column page layout.